# OCaml flush strange behaviour (exiting all threads)

Tags: sockets, ocaml, channel

I try to implement a CLI with 2 commands:

- `run` that spawns an unix socket at `/my/path/file.sock` and produces output
- `watch` that connects to the socket and forward the output to its own output

When I kill the `watch` command, I can't understand why the `run` command is also killed. They don't raise any exception nor sys signal. I noticed that the problems comes from the `flush` function. Once called, it acts like a `exit 0`. How come?

[image]

Here the sources: https://github.com/soywod/comodoro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server has to listen for client disconnection and remove the connection from the *conn* list.
Something like this might work:

```ml
let client_thread conn =
  let in_ch = in_channel_of_descr conn in
  while true do
    try input_line in_ch |> ignore
    with End_of_file ->
     (* Remove conn from !conn and close the conn *)
  done
in

let add_conn () =
  (* ... *)
  Thread.create client_thread conn |> ignore;
  (* ... *)
in
```

Comment: Indeed, I didn't want to listen to the in channel because I don't need, but in fact it's mandatory to know when the client disconnects. Works like a charm now, thanks!